# Replace string with regex and replace if some words match with array

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
str = "John: hey, what's your name?.. :haha \n Stella: :foo :xx: my name is ... stella :xx:"
```

I want to replace all smilies in the list `ary = [":haha", ":xx:", ":foo", ":bar"]` and special characters (except space) with `(.*)` so that it becomes like this:

```
John(.*) hey(.*) what(.*)s your name(.*) Stella(.*) my name is (.*) stella (.*)
```

[image]

I tried this:

```
str.gsub(Regexp.new("^#{ary.join('|')}$")) { |w| "(.*)" }.gsub( /[\W ]+/, "(.*)")
# => "John(.*)hey(.*)what(.*)s(.*)your(.*)name(.*)haha(.*)Stella(.*)my(.*)name(.*)is(.*)stella(.*)"
```

Problem:

- Space still replace

Comment: ` ` is being replaced because you are providing it in the pattern: `[\W ]`. Change it to `[^\w\s]+`

Comment: @CarySwoveland make sure you can see that in my question, I have include with text too, not only an image.

Comment: My apologies. I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried creating a more generic approach, but finally came up with a 3-step approach. Since it seems impossible to filter out multiple consecutive `(.*)`, I am adding a post-process with the 3rd `gsub`:

```
str = "John: hey, what's your name?.. :haha \n Stella: :foo :xx: my name is ... stella :xx:"
ary = [":haha", ":xx:", ":foo", ":bar"]
print str.gsub(Regexp.new("#{ary.join('|')}")) { |w| "(.*)" }.gsub( /(?>\(\.\*\)|[^\w ]+)/, "(.*)").gsub(/\(\.\*\)(?>\s*\(\.\*\))*/,"(.*)")
```

Output of a [sample program](http://ideone.com/DNpw8L):

```
John(.*) hey(.*) what(.*)s your name(.*) Stella(.*) my name is (.*) stella (.*)
```

Comment: @stribizhev : Also use `Regexp.escape`, if some word in array has special character, `str.gsub(Regexp.new(ary.map { |x| Regexp.escape(x) }.join('|'))) { |w| "(.*)" }.gsub( /(?>\(\.\*\)|[^\w ]+)/, "(.*)").gsub(/\(\.\*\)(?>\s*\(\.\*\))*/,"(.*)")`

Comment: @anonymousxxx: a very good hint, since we do not know what the actual smilie list looks like. I assumed they all look like a colon plus letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
s = "John: hey, what's your name?.. :haha \n Stella: :foo :xx: my name is ... stella :xx:"

r = /\?\.\. :haha \n|: :foo :xx:|\.\.\.|:xx:|[^\w ]/

s.gsub(r,'(.*)')
  #=> "John(.*) hey(.*) what(.*)s your name(.*) Stella(.*) my name is (.*) stella (.*)"
```

The only tricky bit concerns the order of the 'or' elements in the regex . In particular, `:` cannot be replaced before three other strings are replaced.

Comment: And now add `..` to the input string, what will you get? Correct, it won't get converted to `(.*)`. You also do not take into account the list of known smilies: they might appear in different contexts.

Comment: @stribizhev, you're right. I confess that I didn't read the entire question (I guess I was mesmerized by the pretty pictures). I made some changes to address the points your made. I assume that if `..` were added it should be replaced by `(.*)(.*)`, but if it (or any number of consecutive periods) should just be just `(.*)` that's an easy change.